# Application of the exponential functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose you have $\$$ 5000 dollar in cash. You plan to put your money on a bank for the next $5$ years. The bank you want to put your money pays $5.2 \% $ of anual interest compounded continously. If you withdraw your money before the $5$ years have passed, you pay a penanlty of $ \$ 70 $. Write a function that describes this:

#### Attempt:

Since it is compounded continously, $F(t) = F_0 e^{.052 t } $ where $F_0 = 5000$. After, adding the penalty, we have a piecewise function:

$F(t) = 5000 e^{.052 t}$ if $t > 5 $ and $F(t) = 5000 e^{.052 t} - 70 $if $t \leq 5 $

Is this a correct formula for my problem?

Comment: Arguably $F(t) = 5000 e^{0.052\times 5}$ if $t \ge 5 $ and $F(t) = 5000 e^{0.052 t} - 70 $ if $0 \lt t \lt 5 $ as you do not know if you get any interest when $t \gt 5$, but you should not have to pay the penalty when $t=5$